# Как сделать, чтобы для разных стран главная иконка приложения была разной?

Tags: android

Нужно сделать локализацию, чтобы в зависимости от страны главная иконка была определенной. Например, для Италии одна, для Франции - другая и так далее.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Поместите иконки в соответствующие папки:

```
drawable-ru-mdpi,
drawable-ru-ldpi,
drawable-ru-hdpi,
drawable-ru-xhdpi,
drawable-ru-xxhdpi,
drawable-ru-xxxhdpi,
drawable-en-mdpi,
drawable-en-ldpi,
drawable-en-hdpi,
drawable-en-xhdpi,
drawable-en-xxhdpi,
drawable-en-xxxhdpi
и т.д.
```

Тогда в зависимости от языка будет отображаться иконка из соответствующей папки.

Для мипмепов такой формат названия папок:

```
mipmap-b+ru+RU
mipmap-b+es+ES
```

Comment: Suvitruf, а если картинка хранится в папке mipmap тоже самое?

Comment: @Anna13 тут всё есть же https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages и тут https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources `mipmap-b+ru+RU`